# How does changing the bit value affect address

Tags: c, pointers, bit

For instance, if the adress of `uint8_t *p` is `00000400`, would `(uint32_t*)(p)` remain `0x00000400` (in hex). Also would `p + 4` simple be `0x00000404` since the `p` is only an 8 bit int pointer?

Comment: There's nothing here about "changing the bit value" ... you changed the type of the pointer.

Comment: Why do you care? The language standard has nothing to say about it. If you want to know if the value stays the same on some particular platform, print it out and see.

Answer (score 0):

On platforms you are likely actually use, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can cast a pointer to uint8_t to a uint32_t.  Dereferencing it may be very slightly suboptimal, but it will work.  If you're on a little endian machine, the results of doing so may surprise you.

`pointer_to_type_t + n` will always be `&pointer_to_type_t[n]` or another way of putting it: `(type_t*)((uint32|uint64)(pointer_to_type_t) + n * sizeof(type_t))`

Comment: " Dereferencing it may be very slightly suboptimal, but it will work. " -- Dereferencing it is *undefined behavior* , unless `p` was obtained by casting a `uint32_t*` to `uint8_t*` -- only such round trips are defined by the C Standard.

Comment: Also, your "another way of putting it" is totally messed up ... the multiplication by sizeof is only appropriate when adding to pointer to some type T for which sizeof(T) == 1.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood you expression. But a) uint32 and uint64 are not standard types and b) pointers aren't guaranteed to fit into uint32_t or even uint64_t. The correct type to use here is intptr_t or simply `char*`.